# Django session id without expiry date and time

Tags: django, session-cookies

In Django there is a session middleware, after authenticating in the site the session id is created in the cookie with expiry date and time (default two weeks), We can over ride this by SESSION_COOKIE_AGE in the settings.py. After the expiration the the session id is removed and site is logged out.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
```

And my question is, is there any way ?that we can override, that it should not contain expiry date and time, is this possible? if anything please suggest me, it will be very great-full. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` to a very large number (31536000 == 1 year). Practically, that's same as saying never expire cookie.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way you can use `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` to instruct Django to *never* expire cookie.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion....In SESSION_COOKIE_AGE it cannot set so, is there any other way of writing some middleware for this.